# How to use SAS to find the last sentence in a document?

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a variable that contains the last sentence of a document. 
The last sentence of the text can be separated by periods, question marks or exclamation points. The ending punctuation may be omitted.

```
if find(text, '.') >0 then last = strip(scan(text,-1,'.'));
else if find(text, '?') >0 then last = strip(scan(text,-1,'?'));
else if find(text, '!') >0 then last = strip(scan(text,-1,'!'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SCAN(string, count <, character-list <, modifier>>)`

Try

```
last = scan ( text, -1, '.?!', 't' );
```

The `scan` function will go from right to left when the count is negative.  Use your sentence delimiters as the character-list to interpret a sentence as a 'word'. Use `t` modifier to trim the string before scanning.